# Push view controller without animating nav bar

Tags: ios, animation, uiviewcontroller

I implemented a slideshow gallery using pop and pushViewController, and would like to improve it by keeping the sliding animation of the view, but removing the sliding animation of the title and buttons in the nav bar. Thus, just setting the animated parameter to NO isn't an option. I did fine the following code:

```
CATransition *navTransition = [CATransition animation];
navTransition.duration = 0.75;
navTransition.timingFunction = [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseIn];

navTransition.type = kCATransitionPush;
navTransition.subtype = kCATransitionPush;
[self.navigationController.navigationBar.layer addAnimation:navTransition forKey:nil];
```

but it adds a slight ease in/ease out, which I would like not to show up.

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a bit complicated, but you can make an image of the nav bar, hide the nag bar, display your image and push your view.  On completion, delete the image and unhide the nav bar.

There is an Apple WWDC vid on making rotation smoother which uses a lot of similar techniques and may be inspirational.
Session 240 - Polishing Your Interface Rotations ( from 2012)